# Script to merge 2 git branches automatically?

Tags: git, merge, branch, jenkins, branching-and-merging

My git repository has 2 branches: master and develop. I want a script that merges all changes from develop to master automatically.

I used Jenkins: The Git plugin clones the repository and then this script (the 'version' variable is a job parameter) is run:

```
# merge
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
git checkout master
git merge -Xtheirs --squash develop -m "v${version}"

# commit
git commit -m "v${version}"

# tag
git tag v${version} -m "v${version}"

# push
git push origin v${version}
```

I tried it on a test repository and it fails with:

> git merge -Xtheirs develop
>   CONFLICT (delete/modify): test.txt deleted in develop and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of test.txt left in tree.
>   Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

**How do I resolve this conflict *automatically*?** I want the script to always add/modify/delete files according to the 'develop' branch, since master is never touched anyway...

Comment: You say that "master is never touched" but you get a conflict anyway? If it were actually never touch, a simple `git merge --ff-only origin/develop` would be enough.

Comment: If you want to _replace_ the master version with the `origin/develop` version and not record a merge commit, why bother with `merge --nosquash`? Wouldn't it be cleaner to just `git checkout master && git reset origin/develop && git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` or similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-X theirs` merge strategy only works to resolve conflicting hunks within a file.  The documentation for these options is in [the `git-merge` man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies):

```
      ours
           This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved
           cleanly by favoring our version. Changes from the other tree
           that do not conflict with our side are reflected to the merge
           result.

           This should not be confused with the ours merge strategy, which
           does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It
           discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history
           contains all that happened in it.

       theirs
           This is opposite of ours.
```

In this case, one branch has deleted the file while the other has modified it, which is a distinct case from a simple conflicting hunk between two branches that have made different modifications.

Comment: Is there a way to make git automatically pick "delete the file" if either has deleted it?

Answer (score 1):

5 years old.... But still relevant.

Here's my solution:
I delete the master branch and create a new master branch from the branch I want to 'merge' from:

```
GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_FROM=`git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed 's!refs\/heads\/!!'`
GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO="master"

git checkout "${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO}"
git checkout "${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_FROM}"

# Delete TO branch
git branch -D "${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO}" || echo "Failed to delete ${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO}"
git push origin :"${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO}" || echo "Failed to push ${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO} delete to origin"

# Create TO branch
git checkout -b "${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO}" || echo "Failed to create local branch ${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO}"
git push origin "${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO}" || echo "Failed to push ${GIT_BRANCH_TO_MERGE_TO} to origin"
```