# Git merge strategy 'theirs' is not resolving modify/delete conflict

Tags: git

When performing a `git merge` with the following options:

`git merge -X theirs master`

There are occasionally conflicted files like so:

> CONFLICT (modify/delete): File_A.java deleted in master and modified
>   in HEAD. Version HEAD of File_A.java left in tree.

However, I would like for the `-X theirs` option to be recognized in these cases, and use the `theirs` version of the change, which is for the file to be **deleted.**

Is there a reason this type of conflict is not automatically resolved, *especially* since I'm providing a specific merge strategy that suggests it should remove the file?

Further, how (if possible) can I update my `merge` command to use the `theirs` version of this type of conflict?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script to merge 2 git branches automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573099/script-to-merge-2-git-branches-automatically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like `theirs` option of `recursive` strategy (this is what you actually use, see the [1]) does not affect tree merging, it is used only for file content merging when both files modified only. I don't really know if there is any merge command option which can do what you want. You could try to make a script which scans conflicted files (with `git status --porcelain`) and then either removes the file (`git rm --force <file>`) or get the remote version of it (`git checkout --theirs <file>`)

[1] https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies

Answer (score 25):

A bit late but might be useful, you can resolve this type of conflict with:

```
git merge -X theirs master
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git rm
```

Basically it means "delete all unmerged files" during the conflict resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> Further, how (if possible) can I update my merge command to use the theirs version of this type of conflict?

You will need to use **Merge Drivers**.
You will need to create your own driver and confutation in the `.gitattribute` file.

---

Here is a list of related Q which might be helpfully to you.
Each one attach this issue forma different angle

- [tell git to use ours merge strategy on specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093540/tell-git-to-use-ours-merge-strategy-on-specific-files)
- [.gitattributes & individual merge strategy for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465122/gitattributes-individual-merge-strategy-for-a-file)
- https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b#.sc08nj3ww