# How to avoid adding deleted files in git merge?

Tags: git, merge

Let's say there are 2 git branches: `master` and `dev`. In `dev` I deleted `foo.txt`. After that in `master` some changes are added to `foo.txt`. When I merge `master` to `dev` `foo.txt` is created although it was deleted from `dev`.

So is there a way to NOT recreate deleted files on `git merge`?

EDIT: [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) pointed out that it will cause conflict and simply add the deleted file again. So the question is rather how to exclude the files from merge that have no counterpart in the target branch.

Comment: Actually if you delete _foo.txt_ in one branch and edit _foo.txt_ in the other, then when you merge them there will be a _conflict_. So you are not describing correctly what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i've understood your issue properly here is what the git log should looks like :

```
* ff3f8a1 (HEAD -> master) changed text
| * 8a4d7d7 (dev) removed file
|/  
* 615d151 initial commit
```

If you do `git merge dev` to merge branch `dev` onto `master`, you will end up with a merge conflict. That's why the file came back. You have to resolve that conflict manualy by either:

- removing the file (`git rm --force <file>`)
- getting the remote version (on the deleted side) of it (`git checkout --theirs <file>`)

`git merge --strategy-option=theirs` won't be able handle those kind of conflicts (modify/delete)

AFAIK there is no proper way arround that without manual conflict resolution, but there are some hacky solutions like this one wich deletes all the files that fail to merge (can be dangerous): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232519/8541886