# rewrite history to undo all changes to a file on current branch in git

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

Suppose I have a feature branch that modifies half a dozen files.  Most of the commits on that branch involve `file.py`.  I eventually realize that there's a potentially better way to implement this feature without touching `file.py` at all.  Is there a way to tweak all the commits on my branch to not touch that file?  I feel that there should be some kind of trick with interactive rebase that does this easily, but I'm not sure what trick that would be.

Of course, I could simply revert the changes as a new commit, but seems a pity to clutter up history for posterity.

Comment: I don't have time to write up the answer as I'm heading out the door, but you can use a conflict resolution with rebase, like `-X ours`. Completely untested, but in theory I believe it will work: step 1: make a commit that causes a conflict, for example, make a commit that deletes `file.py` off of the parent of the first commit you modified `file.py` in. Step 2: rebase `--onto` that delete commit with `-X ours`. This *should* auto resolve conflicts on the file and leave it deleted. Step 3: Now interactive rebase and simply drop the commit that deleted the file.

Comment: I'd suggest using [matt's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72587051/1256452) but also setting a branch name to point to *this* version before you start, so that when your rebase is done, you now have *two* attempts to do what you're doing: one that touches the one file, and one that doesn't. These two attempts are on the new branch and the original branch respectively.

Comment: In other words, run `git branch first-try` and then run the `git rebase -i`.

Comment: Re: scratch-branch: yes, definitely.  I don't usually bother for simple re-bases because I know that I can always just abort, but for something this tricky, I would definitely leave a pristine backup.  By the way, torek, I'd like to thank you again for your answer to my question many months ago about confusing CRLF warning messages.  It came in useful again just a few days ago.

Comment: re: -X ours resolution... that is clever!  I would have probably never thought of that

Comment: I tested out my idea, and it worked. The only caveat is that my original idea was for the "change" to the file to be deleting it, but that didn't work. I suppose Git thinks that a conflict of changes vs a deletion is too wild to go through with it. But when I modified it instead of deleting it, it worked perfectly. I added an answer demonstrating it in action.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, a delete/modify conflict isn't actually "too wild"; rather, the `-X ours/theirs` strategies are designed specifically for [auto resolving conflicting hunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573159/184546).

Comment: Ah so I need to beware that there are two different `ours`... one is "merge strategy" that does what we want here, and the other is an option to a different merge strategy, which does not do what we want (because it tries to actually merge things).

Comment: @MarkVY you can disregard that for the purposes of this question. That note in the documentation is just differentiating between `-X ours` and `-s ours`. The `-X` basically means, do this merge and resolve conflicts where the file is modified on both sides, by automatically picking "ours" or "theirs". The `-s ours` merge is not about conflict resolution at all. It basically means, "merge the commit IDs but ignore all of the changes in those commits". It's often used for capturing historical context without touching your files.

Comment: Right, but it seems that here, I actually want `-s ours` instead of `-X ours` for your trick to work, right?  That is, I don't want to "resolve" conflicts, I want to "ignore" them. Or have I gotten confused?

Comment: I think that note in the last link added confusion. You definitely want `-X ours` in your case. You need to force a conflict, and let `-X ours` auto resolve said conflict for you so you don't need to get involved at multiple commits, as described in matt's answer. The only reason I even linked to that other answer was to explain why the conflict you need to create for this method must be "modify/modify", instead of "delete/modify" which was my original idea in the first comment. `-Xours` won't auto resolve "delete/modify" conflicts, but it will auto resolve "modify/modify".

Comment: But `-X ours` will only "work" for the one conflict that I introduce.  That means I need to introduce at least one conflict for each part of the file that I touched, right?  Sounds error-prone.

Comment: @MarkVY that is a fantastic point! OK, I think I have a fix for this- the edit must be wiping the file or something like that, but not deleting it.

Comment: Okay nice, I will try that.  I keep saying "I will try that" and then not trying it, but really I mean it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be automated by using automatic conflict resolution during the rebase. The algorithm could work like this:

1. Create a branch at the commit containing the last changes for the file(s) in question.
2. Create a new commit on that branch that replaces the entire contents of file(s) with something unique (perhaps even nothing). The point here is to make sure all new changes you wish to ignore will definitely conflict with this change.
3. Rebase your main branch onto (`--onto`) the new temp branch, and use merge strategy "ours" (`-Xours`).
4. Now remove the temporary commit from your branch, using interactive rebase or via another rebase `--onto` as demonstrated below.

Here's a bash script that demonstrates the algorithm in action:

```
#!/bin/bash -v
git init

git branch -m main # name branch main in case that isn't your default

echo asdf > asdf; echo stuff > file.py; git add .; git commit -m "Create commit 1"
echo line2 >> asdf; echo line2 >> file.py; git add .; git commit -m "Create commit 2"
echo line3 >> asdf; echo line3 >> file.py; git add .; git commit -m "Create commit 3"
echo line4 >> asdf; echo line4 >> file.py; git add .; git commit -m "Create commit 4"

git branch main-rebase # make a copy of main for the rebase

# make a branch off of commit 1 (3 commits ago)
git switch -c temp-branch @~3

# make a temp commit that modifies file.py
echo testing > file.py; git add .; git commit -m "wip: change file.py"

# rebase using "ours" strategy to remove all changes to file.py after commit 1
git rebase main-rebase~3 main-rebase --onto temp-branch -Xours

# remove the temporary wip commit from the branch
git rebase main-rebase~3 main-rebase --onto main-rebase~4

# remove the temp branch
git branch -D temp-branch

# show the full log
echo "Oneline graph log of all branches:"
git log --all --graph --oneline

echo "Show history of file.py on main"
git log main --oneline -- file.py

echo "Show history of file.py on main-rebase"
git log main-rebase --oneline -- file.py
```

Comment: It works!  It even dropped all the commits that used to touch only that file :)

Comment: @MarkVY perfect! That makes sense since those commits would be now be empty.

Answer (score 4):

Do an interactive rebase all the way back to the commit before the "start" of the branch (that is, to the most recent reachable commit where this file was still the way you want it). Let's call that commit `abcde`:

```
git rebase -i abcde
```

The Todo list will appear, listing all the commits after that "good" commit.

```
pick 11111
pick 22222
pick 33333
...
```

In the Todo list, mark every commit `edit`.

```
edit 11111
edit 22222
edit 33333
...
```

Save and close the editor. The rebase will begin. When each stage in the rebase stops and waits for your instructions, restore the state of the file in question from before the branch:

```
git restore --source abcde --worktree --staged -- <pathToFile>
git rebase --continue
```

Your editor will ask you whether you want to change the commit message; you don't, so just close the editor, and on we go to the next commit.

When you get to the very end of the process, you will have carried an unchanged file all the way thru the branch.

---

<sub>It is possible to automate everything I just said by using `git filter-repo`, but you asked for a trick with interactive rebase, so that's what I described.</sub>

<sub>Also, note that if you happen know that the file in question was not altered in a particular commit, you can leave that commit set to `pick` in the Todo list and thus save some steps. There are ways to find that out. But my answer is deliberately simple and ignores that issue.</sub>

---

I always like to prove my answer by an illustration. Here's the opening situation:

```
* f2fa796 (HEAD -> main) three
* dc90263 two
* 4861739 one
```

Each commit has a file *a.txt*, and it changes that file from the previous commit, as I shall now show:

```
% git show HEAD:a.txt
aaa
% git show HEAD~1:a.txt
aa
% git show HEAD~2:a.txt
a
```

Very well, let's begin our interactive rebase:

```
% git rebase -i 4861739
```

In the editor, I mark both commits as `edit`, and close the editor. The rebase begins:

```
Stopped at dc90263...  two
You can amend the commit now, with

  git commit --amend 

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

  git rebase --continue
```

So I say:

```
% git restore --source 4861739 --staged --worktree -- a.txt
% git rebase --continue
```

We proceed to the next commit. There is a merge conflict in this file, but that doesn't matter to me:

```
% git restore --source 4861739 --staged --worktree -- a.txt
% git rebase --continue
```

And Git says:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.
```

So now let's inspect the situation again:

```
% git show HEAD:a.txt
a 
% git show HEAD~1:a.txt                                    
a
% git show HEAD~2:a.txt                                    
a
```

That is exactly the desired result.

Comment: Okay, so rather than prevent the merge conflict, or try anything "clever" to resolve it, you basically ignore it and just restore the file to the state we want to end in (which is the initial state).  Doable, but it's O(n) "work" where n is the number of commits we have to "stop" at.  And the constant factor here is large: perhaps even multiple minutes per commit we stop at.  I was hoping for something more like TTT's idea where I only have to do O(1) work regardless of how many commits are on my branch.  I'd heard of filter-repo but it seemed like a scary power tool so I kinda ignored it.

Comment: Agreed, I like TTT's idea too! Give it a try.